# are there more special characters on my phone keypad such as "#"?

Tags: keyboard

I get frustrated with Android because I can't find all the special characters on it for passwords etc that I have on my windows 10 computer.  Is there a trick to finding more special characters?

Comment: That very much depends on the [keyboard app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) you are using. Some (like [Hackers Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)) offer more "special characters" than others.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are. For example try holding letter F it will show $ € £ ¥ ¢ . Try other letters as well.

Answer (score 1):

All of the special characters are there in the default Google keyboard, but you may need to go two screens into the symbols in order to see them.

You probably already know that you can get to the first symbol screen with the numbers by pressing the <kbd>?123</kbd> button.

Once you are on that screen, you can get to the second one by pressing the key that used to be the Shift key, which now says <kbd>=\<</kbd>.